# How Mongo DB or any nosql DB (Hbase, Cassandra) is scalable and having advantage over traditional RDBMS?

Tags: mongodb, cassandra, nosql, hbase

I am still not able to relate in real-time how nosql is beneficial whereas we have indexes too in traditional RDBMS's. If someone can suggest columnar databases advantages in real application particularly in terms of using structure, semistructured or unstructured data.

Answer (score 2):

Largely, it depends on what you want your datastore to do.  If you want to be able to scale to meet storage or operational demands, a RDBMS can only take you so far.

It comes down *how* you can scale to meet demand.  A RDBMS is really only capable of scaling *vertically*.  That is, add more RAM, add more disk, etc.  A distributed (NoSQL) database makes scaling easier by allowing you to add more machine instances.  This is known as scaling *horizontally*.

**Here's an example using Cassandra:**

Let's say I have a 3 node cluster, and my keyspace (database) is also configured with a replication factor (RF) of 3.  This means that each node is responsible for 100% of the data.  I load my data, and it takes up 100GB of disk space (on each node).  Now, while I might have 300GB of data total in my cluster, a single copy of my data is 100GB.

So my product team comes to me and says they need to double the amount of data they have.  I know that I built their 3 node cluster with 200GB drives.  If I did nothing, those drives would pretty much fill-up (and if they didn't they wouldn't leave room for much else).

Now it's up to me to scale the cluster to meet their space demands.  I'll start by adding 3 new nodes to the cluster (for a total of 6), but I'll leave my RF at 3.  This makes each node responsible for 50% of the data, or 50GB.  When my product team loads more data to meet their "doubling" requirement, each node should climb back up to about 100GB.  A single copy of the data is now 200GB.  But with each node responsible for 50%, each 200GB drive still only has 100GB.

**Example #2:**

Let's say that the cluster above with 6 nodes is capable of supporting an operational load of 10,000 operations per second (ops).  My product team comes to me again, saying that for the holiday season they project needing to support 20,000 ops.  As the current cluster can only support half of that, it will choke under the intense throughput, and one or more nodes may crash.

As Cassandra scales linearly, the way to achieve this is to (again) double the size of the cluster.  So I increase it from 6 nodes to 12 nodes, while still maintaining my RF of 3.  After running some performance testing, they verify that it can indeed support 20,000 ops.  As a single copy of my data is 200GB, the total data footprint remains 600GB.  With 12 nodes, each node is now responsible for only 25% of the data, or 50GB.

So scalability is the advantage.  But how about modeling the data?  The main idea in distributed database modeling, is two-fold:

1. Build a table structure which is keyed to distribute well. We don't want uneven amounts of data on each node.
2. Build the key on the table so that it matches our query requirements.

One of the drawbacks of a NoSQL database, is that your query patterns become restricted.  In an effort to cut down on network time, you want to ensure that your query can be served by a *single* node.

This usually means using *natural* keys, as those are more in-line with what you are asking of your data.  Surrogate keys (alpha, numerical, or both) distribute well, but aren't really useful for querying.  User "Bob Jones" might be id "3582346556230" in my system.  But when I want to query Bob's data, I'll probably never want to ask for it by "3582346556230," because that doesn't mean anything to the application or the context in which the data is used.

Also, you *want* your data to have structure.  Unstructured data is un-queryable data.  Simple as that.  If you want unstructured data to be queryable, you need to parse-out its identifying aspects to be used as keys.  You don't want to "search" or run `SELECT * FROM` queries.  Full table scans in NoSQL databases are even more resource consuming than their RDBMS counterparts, because they have to check each node, sort through replicas, and thus incurs extra network time.

NoSQL databases give you the ability to scale (for increases in data or demand).  But it's important to note that their scalability can make some things (which a RDBMS might be good at), more difficult than you're used to.

Comment: Aaron, Chris, deceze You guys explained well. I have got most of my queries resolved. I am still struggling to get in what scenarios nosql (HBASE, Cassendra) will be required as till now i always get structured data to work upon which i am managing easily with MySQL or in Hadoop Hive.

Answer (score 1):

The R in RDBMS, ***r**elational*, is the biggest thing missing from Mongo. There's very little to no way to make the database understand how entries in different <strike>tables</strike> collections *relate* to each other. One of the big strengths of RDBMSs is the ability to define constraints which the database will enforce, most typically foreign key constraints which ensure that an id in one table refers to an existing id in another table.

One requirement for the database to be able to enforce such constraints is obviously that everything needs to go through one source of truth and there needs to be one central entity cross-checking the data; it cannot be decentralised since discrepancies between two different primary sources can lead to data inconsistencies.

In Mongo, each data blob is pretty much independent. It doesn't refer to other entries in any way enforced by the database. Mongo also has weak to no [ACID guarantees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID), meaning there's little protection against [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) inserts or updates. In a word: Mongo makes little guarantees with regards to data consistency and mostly offloads these kinds of concerns to the application layer. That allows it to work more decentralised.

E.g. a good way to scale Mongo is to have many secondary servers which replicate a primary server for read-only access. There's no guarantee that the primary and secondaries will be in sync at any given time, it may take a couple of seconds for data written to the primary to trickle to the secondaries. But this allows you to have a virtually unlimited number of secondary read-only servers, which is great for scaling a database under heavy read load.

The way specifically Mongo handles its clusters also allows it to have a very high uptime, as the cluster will reorganise itself into primaries and secondaries automatically if a server goes down. This even allows for rolling maintenance without any client downtime.

Not having to enforce complex constraints or transaction consistency during writing also allows a more fire-and-forget style of writing to the database, which can be much faster. Again, at the cost of allowing inconsistent data. Which is why most writing pretty much means atomically updating a single document in a collection with no guarantees about other documents, which is something of a different paradigm than RDBMS transactional updates across many tables.

I would not recommend Mongo for storing things like a financial ledger, which heavily relies on transactional guarantees for consistency. However, things like Twitter are a perfect case for it: many independent snippets of data which must be read by a massive number of clients.

Comment: Thanks deceze..It's useful details around the Mongo characteristics. The only thing is debatable here is if i have a twitter feeds coming in or a live logs streaming then a suitable option will be a nosql rather a RDBMS because the data is unstructured in nature. Though, if we keep this case apart, how a SQL is not a worthy option as a huge size of data can also be stored in flat table that can be queried as well (provided no relation maintained).

Comment: Well, other characteristics is the kind of indices the database provides, leading into what kind of queries you can do, and whether the database requires upfront schema specifications vs. letting you work in an unstructured way and what kind of cost/benefit that has.

Comment: Just an aside: "financial ledger, which heavily relies on transactional guarantees for consistency." - Very few financial things use transactional guarantees or care about consistency. Just track transactions and calculate totals with landmarks from periodic jobs. Going below zero is even considered a good thing in some institutions as it means its ok too charge additional fees or interest. Very high availability and safety in never losing the transactions is more important than the consistency which is why many banks use technologies like Cassandra.

Comment: Maybe an additional point, is ease of use. Mongo is crazy easy to setup and get going immediately for building new systems and being unstructured makes incremental changes easier.

Comment: @Chris Fair point, a ledger wasn't the best example for relational data.